# VueJS/Nuxt Style binding only works on hard reload

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've got a Vue/Nuxt project and I'm having a bit of a weird issue.

I have a component that renders a button with various CSS styles and that's all working fine. I've also got some styles that I need to control via props, so I have these bound to a style tag. This all works on the initial load of the page, however, if I navigate to the page using a Nuxt link, or I make changes to the component and HMR reloads it, then the inline styles disappear.

I've tried to narrow this down a bit by including an inline style that comes from a prop, and an inline style that I have just hardcoded. As before, the style coming from the prop isn't rendered, but the hardcoded style is.

I've had a good Google about but can't find anything that suggests I'm doing something wrong.

**EDIT**: So I've narrowed it down a bit. It's not the props, it's the linear gradient. Even a hardcoded linear gradient doesn't render.

Here's the component snippet.

```
<template>
  <span class="button-link" :class="{ 'button-link--primary': primary }">
    <span
      class="button-link__gradient-wrapper-one"
      :style="{
        backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${colorStart}, ${colorEnd});`,
        color: 'red'
      }"
    />
    <span
      class="button-link__gradient-wrapper-two"
      :style="{
        backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${colorEnd}, ${colorStart});`,
        color: 'red'
      }"
    />
    <button v-if="!href && !to" class="button-link__button">
      <slot />
    </button>
    <a v-if="href" class="button-link__button" :href="href"><slot /></a>
    <nuxt-link v-if="to" :to="to" class="button-link__button">
      <slot />
    </nuxt-link>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    primary: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    colorStart: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    colorEnd: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    href: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    to: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've also tried adding these styles from a computed property but that doesn't make a difference

Comment: I also have this same issue with `'background-url'` from a computed property

Answer (score 1):

Try with a computed properties. For example:

```html
<template>
  ...
    <span
      class="button-link__gradient-wrapper-one"
      :style="gradientStart"
    />
    <span
      class="button-link__gradient-wrapper-two"
      :style="gradientEnd"
    />
  ...
</template>
```

```js
computed: {
  gradientStart() {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${this.colorStart}, ${this.colorEnd})`,
      color: "red"
    };
  },
  gradientEnd() {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${this.colorEnd}, ${this.colorStart})`,
      color: "red"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already. It seems to be related to it being a linear gradient. For some reason Vue won't render that unless it's a hard reload.

Comment: @ScottBamforth that's odd. I tried to reproduce the issue in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/7y7ryvxr4q) and it works (in a basic way). Maybe try to reproduce your issue too with your correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out;

**Does not work:**

```
backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${colorEnd}, ${colorStart});`
```

**Does work:**

```
backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to left, ${colorEnd}, ${colorStart})`
```

Please not the `;` removed on the last snippet.